# Desktop Notifications from Safari Have No Sound

Tags: macbook-pro, notifications

I have enabled desktop notifications from a few different web apps with Safari as my default browser.  While desktop notifications successfully come through, there is never a notification sound.

Using Google Calendar as an example, I have allowed notifications for calendar.google.com within Safari's preferences:

[image: Safari preferences]

Within my Google Calendar settings, I have desktop notifications and sound enabled:

[image: Google Calendar settings]

Within Notifications in System Preferences, "play sound" is enabled for Safari itself:

[image: System Preferences]

And while there is a separate entry for calendar.google.com in System Preferences, there is no "show sound" option there.

Sound Effects are enabled in System Preferences and set to play through the same audio output as all other media.  Other media and sound effects from my Mac play just fine, and notification sounds do occur for this same Google Calendar account on my mobile devices.  I'm just about out of ideas for things to check.

I'm on Monterey, with M1.

Comment: Have you found any solution? I have the same problem on Ventura M1.